# How to perform a MySQL row lock and delete rows using PHP?

Tags: mysql, locking, innodb

LAMP stack - so code is PHP

I have an innodb table - called queueTable

There is a cron job that runs every 15 minutes that queries the DB to figure out if any records need to be put into queueTable.  Sometimes there are NO records added to queueTable, and other times there may be over 1,000 records added to queueTable.

What needs to happen is every row in queueTable needs to be read, a process needs to be performed, and then that row needs to be deleted.

Currently, I have two daemon jobs that do nothing but query queueTable every 5 seconds.

One job reads all odd row records, the other reads all even row records.  There are two jobs in order to get all the processing done quickly (two jobs are better than one).

I'd like to create like 20 daemons to all go at the queueTable - thus cutting the time a row lives in the queueTable to a minimum.

Think of it as a mail queue (it isn't but for a good example that works).

I need to empty the queue as quickly as possible.

I can do a transaction and lock the row, but that doesn't prevent another daemon from trying to lock the same row.  What will happen is if a daemon tries to read a locked row - it will wait for it.  BUT the daemon that locked that row is going to delete it.  Not sure what the second daemon does at that point?

What is the best way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks!

BTW - I have tried pthreads - and found it really doesn't help much in terms of throughput.  IE.  the process that reads a record and processes it before it get's the next record - if I do that in a multi-threaded mode (IE each process is a new thread) the time to empty the queue is the same as doing each row one at a time.  At least in my testing that's been the case.

Comment: locks are atomic. either it succeeds, or it fails. you can't have two different clients locking the same record, as only one could ever succeed.

Comment: database tables are transactional and if your keys are defined correctly simply running a query and performing the step or multiple steps should be faster then trying to create a php threaded solution as php is stateless. Why are you doing this? Or why do you think this is a good method to solve your issue? You could probably even used stored procedures here.

Comment: To address why I'm doing this... it is a timing issue.  The information we are processing needs to be processed within one minute - regardless of how many records there are.  Right now with the two daemon jobs, when that queueTable has several thousand records in it - the daemons process those records in about 4 minutes.  The information is fairly time critical - so getting that data processed within one minute is a significant requirement.

Comment: @LenS The real solution is to do something with RabbitMQ or another queue technology. There are php versions of it but here is a example: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html. This should do you a bit better. As stated in my previous comment the only better solution is stored procedures that activate as rows are added to the table. Ideally with the queue you would have it create individual workers as the data is available and not as one giant "batch".

Comment: In an ideal world that may work, but the jobs that create these records do so in batches... takes about 15 seconds to create about 4,000 records.  I'll check into rabitMq thou

Answer (score 0):

My mantra for implementing queues in MySQL:  "Don't queue it, just do it!"

Multi-processing with PHP is not that easy to achieve.  Perl (also part of Lamp) is much better.  Furthermore, since this is a background task, keep the web server and browser (Apache + IE) out of the picture; they are a lot of overhead.

How long does it take to process one "item"?  If it takes only a few seconds, then `BEGIN; SELECT one item FOR UPDATE; process it; COMMIT;`

If it takes longer than that, do not put `BEGIN...COMMIT` around everything; instead do something like:

`SET autocommit=1`

1. `$id = SELECT id ... WHERE process_id IS NULL ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1;`  (Or you could grab 10 and have an inner loop of steps 2..5.)
2. `UPDATE ... SET process_id = $pid WHERE id = $id AND process_id IS NULL;` and check to see if it worked.  Note that the `SELECT` and `UPDATE` are deliberately not in a transaction; this is to minimize interference.  However, without transactions, there is a modest chance that another thread will grab it.  If so, the rows_affected will be 0; go back to step 1.
3. Process the item
4. `UPDATE (or DELETE) ... SET process_id = NULL WHERE id = $item;` -- release the lock
5. `sleep(1)` -- delay a little -- to avoid artificially swamping the system.  This may need tuning.
6. go back to step 1.

You can have any number of threads doing that.

Comment: So then transaction locking (from multiple threads) would work? So that all records would be processed (and deleted when the process / transaction was committed) and there would be no chance for any row to be processed more than once?

Comment: Step 1 gets a tentative item.  Step 2 is the tricky one: it _atomically_ grabs it or gets zero rows affected.  Step 4 deletes to row from consideration.

Comment: I updated steps 2 and 4.  There are many variants on how to do it, but that is the general idea.

Comment: I designed it to have very little locking.  Step 1 may need a better index to minimize its time.  Steps 2 and 4 (assuming `PRIMARY KEY(id)`) has very low lock time.  By not using transactions, but instead autocommit, each statement stands alone.  (Step 3 may have transactions; but that is another matter.)  Step 1 is the biggest overhead; focus on it.

Comment: Actually BEGIN, SELECT for UPDATE, process, DELETE, COMMIT seems to work. 

I had two jobs doing the same thing against a test table with 8500 rows.  First iteration, instead of DELETE, I did UPDATE and set a counter to keep track of how often the row was updated, and set another field as processed - so the SELECT included  where processed = '0'   

Ran the simulation many times - the counter always came up to 1 and all rows got updated.

Changed it to delete the record when done - seems to also work as I'd expect.

I'm not sure how much overhead there doing it like that, but it does work.

Comment: Yes, that should work.  But only if the entire transaction is "fast enough" or does not "block others".  My 6-step design is for applications where it is not "fast enough".